# Drop down for Unique Values for a ArcGIS Custom Tool

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

Can an ArcGIS Tool have a drop down field with unique values derived from a list? For example, user selects a table, the tool will then find all of the values in field X and populate a drop based on this.

I've been playing with parameters but can't get anything to work. The closest I got was is creating a drop down with the field names.

[image: ArcGIS Tool Box]

Comment: This is done using tool validation.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-validation?sort=frequent

Comment: Code to get unique field values: https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/create-a-list-of-unique-field-values/

Comment: @PolyGeo and KHibma thanks that really helps answer my questions. Would either of you to add it as an answer?